# how to fill Dataset with custom built DataTable using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, report, datasource

I have to make a report.rdlc where i have to pass a dataset to it

I have DataTable made using C# not SQLDATAADAPTER other wise it can be filled as

```
      adpt.fill(ds);
```

but i have only custom built DataTable using c# having columns and rows
How to make it **datasource** of report or make it **dataset**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Simple...  A Dataset is nothing but a collection of "DataTable" instances.  You should be able to do via..

```
var DS = new DataSet();
YourCustomPopulatedDataTable.TableName = "SomeTable";
DS.Tables.Add( YourCustomPopulatedDataTable );
```

What * have done was created a baseline "ReportManager" class, but after I get the dataset with data back, I Write the XML output but also the XSD something like

```
DS.WriteXmlSchema( "MyXYZReport.xsd");   // the report will get this in a moment
DS.WriteXml( "MyXYZReport.xml");
```

Then, modify your project and add the ".xsd" file created so you don't have to fat-finger the schema for the report.  So, the first time through, I query the data, generate the XSD/XML and stop before the actual report.  Then, modify the project and add the XSD to it.

Now, open your rdlc.  On the left-side you should have a panel for "Report Data".  If not, click anywhere within your report, but not a specific object. Just enough to give focus you are working with the .RDLC.  Then, click on "View" from the menu and the last item should show "Report Data" option.  Once that is displayed, it will show how / where data comes from, parameters, images, data sources, data sets, etc.

Click on DataSets, right-click to Add Dataset and pick the .XSD you added to your project.  This will display a dialog prompting with a "Name" to refer as in the report, then a data source.  The Data Source should list the name such as "MyXYZReport".  Under that will be "Available Datasets" and have the name of the tables within your dataset.  Notice the one line change I did above to "name" the table before writing the XSD.  Whatever that name is ("SomeTable" ), should be listed in the Available Datasets.  Select that.  Then, from my purpose, I change the "Name" of the dataset (the first field in the dialog) to the same value "SomeTable".  This way, I am not guessing at which name is which.  They will all refer to this as "SomeTable".

Now, in the report when you start adding controls, the expression dialog will show your "known" datasets (table instances) and associated fields to go.

Comment: but how to make report.rdlc textboxes to view data of datatable passed